# объединение таблиц с разным типом полей и форматом записи

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Есть 2 таблицы.

В первой есть поле **SerialNo** типа **nvarchar**, в которое записываются восьмизначные значения в виде '20030001', '20030002' и т.д.

Во второй таблице есть такое же поле **SerialNo**, но с типом **int** (пример 30001, 30002).

Как соединить таблицы в запросе по содержимому этих полей?

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, так (если лидирующих нулей нет):

```
select * from tbl1 a inner join tbl2 b on a.SerialNo = CONCAT('200', b.SerialNo)
```

или так

```
select * from tbl1 a inner join tbl2 b on a.SerialNo = 20000000 + b.SerialNo
```

Comment: Небольшое замечание: лучше такие запросы не использовать на постоянной основе. Они ужасно оптимизируются.

Answer (score 2):

Может так? 
`SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE SUBSTRING(Table1.SerialNo, 4, 5) = CONVERT(nvarchar(8), Table2.SerialNo)`

Comment: Видимо, имелось в виду что-то типа SUBSTRING(Table1.SerialNo, 4, 5)

Comment: Небольшое замечание: лучше такие запросы не использовать на постоянной основе. Они ужасно оптимизируются.